# Stop running thread group in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a processMedia method which takes like 1 mint and multiple threads hits the same method when ever user refresh the page.

So after any of the running thread finish process that media, I want to stop all the threads which running for process that media.

So I need to kind of map all threads with media id and stops them. How can I do it in proper way?

Comment: ExecutorService and invokeAny, then support interrupting / cancellation.

Comment: See [`invokeAny`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny(java.util.Collection)) : "Executes the given tasks, returning the result of one that has completed successfully (i.e., without throwing an exception), if any do. Upon normal or exceptional return, tasks that have not completed are cancelled."

Comment: So how can I group all the threads processing a media id?